# Python - How to write varying number of 'if (condition) or if(condition)'?

Tags: python, list, parsing, if-statement

I was trying to make a parser in Python which goes through multiple files, searches for given words, and returns all the lines that contain that string.

The method I am using is making the same line from the document containing a searched word print multiple times, if that line contains multiple words that user is trying to search.

The search method I am using currently is :

```
for line in range(0,length_of_documents):
    for word in range(0,words):
        if words[word] in document[line]:
            print(document[line])
```

To overcome this, I need to write something like :

```
for line in range(0,length_of_documents):
    for word in range(0,words):
        if words[0] in document[line] or if words[1] in document[line] or if words[2] in document[line]:
            print(document[line])
```

But I don't know how many words the user can enter for the search string. 
What is a possible solution for this?

I have used eval() function which gets passed in the string dynamically generated 'if words[0] in document[line] or if words[1] in document[line] or........' during runtime, but that does not work. I get syntax error at 'if'.

Comment: you seem to have muddled up some of the basic structures, such as loops and why they exist, and how to iterate through a list. I would highly recommend running your own code line by line, and thinking through what is happening. And if youve been following some tutorial, i think you need to find a different one.

Comment: You are right... I might need to concentrate more on basics first. Thanks. I will try to go through a variety of tutorials to get the basics fitted in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if` introduces the entire statement, not each individual condition.

```
if words[0] in document[line] or words[1] in document[line] or words[2] in document[line]:
    print(document[line])
```

This can be written more concisely, especially since you want to iterate over *all* of `words`, using the `any` function.

```
if any(x in document[line] for x in words):
    print(document[line])
```

It also looks like you simply want to iterate over each element of `document`, with no particular interest in the index.

```
for line in document:
    if any(x in line for x in words):
        print(line)
```

Comment: Oh my. That was such a silly mistake from my end. Writing 'if' multiple times.
But I could not have figured out the logic using 'any' like you have written.
I guess I have long ways to go.
Thanks for help though :) I appreciate it.